# Transfer Settings/Config for Gnome 3

Tags: configuration, backup, gnome3

I recently accidentally borked my Linux Mint 18.2 installation and I am going to have to re-install.

I want to make a back up of my config files for my desktop (Gnome 3) because of how much I customized it and I want to save time. My command line still works so I can run commands but no GUI.

I know I can run

```
apt-mark showmanual > installed_apt.txt && snap list > installed_snap.txt
```

to make a list of everything I have installed, which will help get the right applications, dependencies, etc. But is there a command or method I can use to get hold of the configuration file/files so I can just copy/past the contents into the new installation's config files?

Gnome 3 is not what borked my system. So transferring those settings will not damage it because of that, I am sure.

Even just where those files are located would be useful! Thanks!